# react hooks component not get new props value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

- i have 3 component depends on its father value and onChange to send value
- but [console shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHL0W.png)
- its always 0,1,0,1
- expect behaviour should be 0,1,2,3,4,5
- should i just use props.value or add a new state like [value,setValue] in each component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'


const Grand=(props)=>{
  const {onChange,value} = props

  useEffect(()=>{
    setInterval(()=>{
      console.log(`grad props value:${value}`)
      onChange(value+1)
    },1000)
  },[])

  return (
    <div>grand:{value}</div>
  )
}

const Children=(props)=>{
  const {onChange,value} = props
  return (
    <div>children:{value}
    <Grand
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [value,setValue]=useState(0)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Children
          value={value}
          onChange={e=>setValue(e)}
        />
        app:{value}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should update the state that is dependent on the old state. So pass function whose first argument is old state and return value will be the newState or updated value.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-nova-59rmo?file=/src/App.js:120-303)

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`grad props value:${value}`);
      onChange((oldState) => {
        return oldState + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use function wwith preState in `onChange`

```
setInterval(()=>{
  onChange(preVal => {
    console.log(`grad props value:${preVal }`)
    return preVal + 1
  })
},1000)
```

And update onChange

```
onChange={setValue}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Inside Grand Component useEffect you need to do following changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`grad props value:${value}`);
      onChange(value + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [value]);
```